# Time out error in AWS Lambda even after uodating memory and time out settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, python-3.6, boto3

I am trying to list all the `EC2` instances that are of `t2.micro` type, `running` in `Sydney` region. I have written a Lambda function in Python (`Python 3.6`). Below is my code:

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    response = client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                'Values': [
                    'running',
                ],
            },
            {
                'Name': 'instance-type',
                'Values': [
                    't2.micro',
                ],
            },
            {
                'Name': 'availability-zone',
                'Values': [
                    'ap-southeast-2',
                ],
            },
        ],
    )

    print(response)
 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I have given all necessary permissions for Lambda including `AmazonEC2FullAccess`, `AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess` and `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`. I adjusted my memory till `3GB` and time out value to `15 minutes`. Still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Lambda configured for a VPC?

Comment: Hi Chris, Yes it is configured to the VPC that contains EC2 instances

Comment: Can you validate each of the subnets configured have a NAT Gateway for outbound traffic or whether you are using a VPC endpoint for the EC2 service?

Comment: My EC2 instance is sitting in a publci subnet. It has gott a security group attached that is allowing traffic from ports 80, 22 and 443. Besides, I have also got a NAT instance sitting in the public subnet.

Comment: This would be for the subnets you have assigned to the Lambda though as these will be contacting the EC2 API

Comment: To theLambda function, I have attached the 2 public subnets that my VPC posses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223398/discussion-between-alla-sasikanth-and-chris-williams).

Comment: Shouldn't AZ be `ap-southeast-2a` or `ap-southeast-2b` or similar, not only `ap-southeast-2`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Even without that filter, I was getting a `TimedOut` error.

Answer (score 0):

- Unfortunately I can't comment. If you use a VPC on lambda without NAT gateway boto3 won't work.
- By the way,if you are trying to describe instances only through lambda you don't need to configure any VPC.
- use this link to [create a NAT gateway](https://medium.com/@pra4mesh/internet-access-to-aws-lambda-in-a-vpc-6f7b65845f1d)

Comment: Just to clarify the above: If an AWS Lambda function is _not_ configured to use a VPC, then it has automatic access to the Internet. This means that the Lambda function will be able to make the API call.

Comment: Yes, But this answer might be helpful for people using VPCs in lambda,like connect to RDS which doesn't allow connections from outside.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came down to the Lambda being associated with public subnets that use an internet gateway.

As the Lambda will connect outbound via the VPC it cannot connect to the internet without a NAT, this is because the Lambda itself is not granted a public IP address which stops the functionality of the internet gateway from working.

Alternatively for many services you can instead make use of a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html), in your case (EC2) there is a endpoint for this. It is important to understand that whilst your EC2 instances are in a VPC the EC2 API operations are performed against the EC2 service rather than interacting with the resources of your VPC.